# FileReader.readAsDataURL() errors only when debugging in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, filereader

My code is working as expected in both chrome and IE. It updates a modal placeholder div with the source of a new image selected using an input type file. When debugging in chrome only (debugging in IE works fine) and a breakpoint is placed on the readAsDataURL method it errors and breaks. Can anyone explain why it's producing this error?

Error:

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader':
The object is already busy reading Blobs.(anonymous function)
@ pageName.aspx?id=1234:192m.event.dispatch
@ jquery.min.js:3r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

My code:

```
$("#imageInput").change(function () {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            $("#modalImagePlaceHolder").attr("src", e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    } else {
        $("#modalImagePlaceHolder").attr("src", $("#defaultImage").attr("src")).width(480).height(385);

    }
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't worry about this specific issue. My bet is that the debugging tool is trying to access the data in memory while the FileReader object is already in loading state.